# Search Button in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I want to Search the boxes linked to Sheets. Is there any way that I can do that with Search Button and Text Box? I put the image below.

[image]

These ASD, BCD etc. they are all linked to sheets. And like you see I want to use SearchBox and the TextBox to Search these ASD, BCD... But I don't know how to turn that CommandButton to Search with command. Help me on this please.

Comment: use [find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

Comment: I suppose that you search between the text boxes values. Am I right? Otherwise, I do not see why mentioning them... But who knows... If my supposition is correct, are your text boxes ActiveX controls?

Comment: Do you ask a question only for the sake of asking?

Comment: @FaneDuru Not at all. I was busy in 2 days and I couldn't find any time to work on that project. Unfortunately it will continue few days so I can't focus on that too but soon I will try the codes and answer you all.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to search between your text boxes values and your controls are of ActiveX type, please try the next code:

```
Sub searchTextBoxesVal()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, s As OLEObject
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your worksheet
   For Each s In sh.OLEObjects
        If s.Name <> "SearchBox" Then
            If s.Object.Value = sh.OLEObjects("SearchBox").Object.Value Then
                Stop
                'do whatever you need with the found value
            End If
        End If
   Next
End Sub
```

If not, please better specify what you need.